# Display the datein calendar Format LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, html

I have the Json Object which will return the dates as below.

Now i have create an html table where static header will be week days  (Monday to Sunday). Now dynamically iterating over list, date needs to be placed as the date range.
Expecting to display the above object in below format.

[image]

**Json Object**

```
[
   {       
      "timeSheetDate":"Dec 01st Tue",       
      "timeSheetDateId":"a074W00001APTOUQA5",       
      "timeSheetUnformatDate":"2020-12-01"
   },
   {       
      "timeSheetDate":"Dec 02nd Wed", 
      "timeSheetDateId":"a074W00001APTOVQA5",      
      "timeSheetUnformatDate":"2020-12-02"
   },
   {       
      "timeSheetDate":"Dec 03rd Thu",       
      "timeSheetDateId":"a074W00001APTOWQA5", 
      "timeSheetUnformatDate":"2020-12-03"
   },
   {      
      "timeSheetDate":"Dec 04th Fri", 
      "timeSheetDateId":"a074W00001APTOXQA5",      
      "timeSheetUnformatDate":"2020-12-04"
   },
   {
       "timeSheetDate":"Dec 05th Sat",     
      "timeSheetDateId":"a074W00001APTOYQA5",     
      "timeSheetUnformatDate":"2020-12-05"
   },
   {       
      "timeSheetDate":"Dec 06th Sun",  
      "timeSheetDateId":"a074W00001APTOZQA5",      
      "timeSheetUnformatDate":"2020-12-06"
   },
   
   ....
   ....
    {
       
      "timeSheetDate":"Dec 31st Thu",
      "timeSheetDateId":"a074W00001APTOyQAP",
      "timeSheetUnformatDate":"2020-12-31"
   }
   
]
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_header-hidden"
                            style="border: 1px solid black; width: 100%;">
                            <thead style="border: 1px solid black;">
                                <tr class="">
                                    <th class="" style="background: #03A9F4;border: 1px solid black;" scope="col">
                                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-truncate slds-text-color_inverse"
                                            style="font-size: initial;" title="Time Sheet Date">
                                            Monday</div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="" style="background: #03A9F4;border: 1px solid black;" scope="col">
                                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-truncate slds-text-color_inverse"
                                            style="font-size: initial;" title="Regular">Tuesday
                                        </div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="" style="background: #03A9F4;border: 1px solid black;" scope="col">
                                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-truncate slds-text-color_inverse"
                                            style="font-size: initial;" title="Regular"> Wednesday
                                        </div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="" style="background: #03A9F4;border: 1px solid black;" scope="col">
                                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-truncate slds-text-color_inverse"
                                            style="font-size: initial;" title="Regular"> Thursday
                                        </div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="" style="background: #03A9F4;border: 1px solid black;" scope="col">
                                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-truncate slds-text-color_inverse"
                                            style="font-size: initial;" title="Regular"> Friday
                                        </div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="" style="background: #03A9F4;border: 1px solid black;" scope="col">
                                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-truncate slds-text-color_inverse"
                                            style="font-size: initial;" title="Regular"> Saturday
                                        </div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="" style="background: #03A9F4;border: 1px solid black;" scope="col">
                                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-truncate slds-text-color_inverse"
                                            style="font-size: initial;" title="Regular"> Sunday
                                        </div>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <template for:each={timesheetDetails} for:item="tsdt" for:index="index">
                                    <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={tsdt.timeSheetDateId}>
                                        <td>
                                            <lightning-input type="checkbox" label={tsdt.timeSheetDate}
                                                name={tsdt.timeSheetDateId} onchange={handleOncheckCopy}
                                                checked={tsdt.selectedTimesheetDateForCopy}>
                                            </lightning-input>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </template>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

How do we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As with all iterated rendering in LWC, you simply need to make sure your iterated data is structured in your JavaScript to make it easy to render.

In this case you may want to split the data into weeks, a week per row.

Regardless you must first make sure the data is aligned with the day of week by padding the front of your data array with "blank values" as needed.

(I have assumed your data is already sorted by ascending dates)

You get the day of week using the standard JavaScript `Date.getDay()`, which returns an integer between 0 and 6 (note that which day is the first day of week, i.e. 0, is locale dependent - you can work this out for yourself). If your first data entry's date doesn't have day 0 then pad the array with empty values until your first data is in the required index to match its day.

Now all you have to do is split your array into an array of arrays of (up to 7) entries - so you get each row of your grid. You also just ensure that the rendering checks for "empty values" and shows just an empty entry in the grid.

NB: You don't need to do the splitting if you use a flex box to do the layout, but you'll still want to do the initial offsetting.